# Javascript does not replace words with German umlaut

Tags: javascript

Maybe my approach is totally wrong but I want to split long German words into two with replace so text can be read faster.
My code looks like this:

```
selectedText = selectedText.replace(/(Sensibilitäts|Wahrnehmungs)(\w{3})/g,'$1- $2');
```

So this replaces 
Wahrnehmungsstörungen in Wahrnehmungs- störungen but not Sensibilitätsstörungen in Sensibilitäts- störungen. Why that? It seems that the ä in Sensibilitäts seems to make the difference.

Comment: `\w === [A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: Then why it matches first one ?

Comment: Fun fact: for me, it works for neither of them.

Comment: Ha, I now why it didn't work ;-) There was no meta charset utf-8 in the html file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your page or this javascript file is not in UTF-8 (Which is javascript primary encoding), or just file encoding is different.

Please also check what is in `selectedText` using console.log .

Answer (score 0):

For me both cases don't work because `\w` doesn't include umlauts. It works with this `/(Sensibilitäts|Wahrnehmungs)([\wäöüÄÖÜ]{3})/g` though.

Edit: I don't know though why you want exactly three of these characters `{3}`.

Answer (score 0):

When I try your example none of them works. But if I change {3} to + both of them works, that is txt.replace(/(Sensibilitäts|Wahrnehmungs)(\w+)/g,'$1- $2');

If the ä is problematic, it may be some kind of encoding problem (Latin1 vs UTF-8 vs HTML entities). I did my test in a javascript console window.